# Response JSON error - Type is not supported when using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

**EDIT:**

I outputted the array and @apokryfos had mentioned something about resources not being able to be serialized.

Here is how some debug output looks: (Removed some information that is more sensitive)
[Stream in Timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdWUf.png)
It is my timestamp causing the issue.  If I do

```
unset($user["timestamp"]);
```

Then almost everyone's solution works.  So, the real reason was the resources was in there for my timestamp.   How do I stop or fix that?  I tried to do

```
 public $timestamps = false;
```

### This did not have any changes.

I have read through the documentation and a few tutorials.  Sadly, I can't seem to find any documentation on what is returned and what functions are available for use when using Eloquent.  Maybe I am just missing it.

However, I am using this code in my controller.

```
public function find($userName){
    $user = UserSecurity::where('userName', $userName)->get();
    //dd($user);
    return Response()->json(['data' => $user], 200);
}
```

This is my router code.

```
$router->get('/UserSecurity/find/{userName}', ['uses'=>'UserSecurityController@find']);
```

I know that it is pulling the correct data from the database as if I uncomment the `dd($user)` I can see it on screen.  However, if I try to send a response through `Response()->json(..)` it fails with this screen.
[Image of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3F9.png)

I know I am probably using Response() incorrectly, but I have actually tried a number of different ways.  Some just show empty responses and some crash similarly.

I have tried removing `get()` which from what I have found just returns nothing as there are no results.  I have tried `Response($user)` and it was empty.  I have tried `return Response()->json($user);` with the same type unsupported error.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Changing a few code for testing.  I changed to this

```
public function find($userName){
    $user = UserSecurity::where('userName', $userName)->get()->toJson();
    $user = json_encode($user);
    return Response($user);
}
```

This returns **false** . I am not sure where the boolean is coming from.  The original dd($user) actually has the correct information from the DB, so I know it is doing the query correct.

Comment: i think this is happening cause is imposible to return all the response as a json, cause response have the headers included that does not match the json schema. 
try removing the headers from the response if is the case.

Comment: To debug this do `$user->map->jsonSerialize()->dd()` and check if there are any values that cannot be serialised to JSON like e.g. resources (for any reason)

Comment: @apokryfos Wow, ok so I just found that it does have a stream resource.  Could this be the issue?  I will test some things while I wait for a response.

Comment: yes PHP can't JSON serialise system resources. It's strange that a model has that in its `jsonSerialize` method to begin with, if you have accessors that create resources then maybe exclude them from the jsonSerialize via [$hidden](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Comment: @apokryfos if you can make that into an answer I can select it. That fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: @marfo I've posted an answer but I am still left with more questions: (1) You say `unset($user['timestamp'])` works however in your code `$user` is the result of `UserSecurity::where...->get()` which should return an eloquent collection. This should not have any properties other than the array of results. (2) I still don't know why timestamp would be a resource to begin with. Normally timestamps come back either as strings or with the correct cast as `Carbon` instances

Comment: @apokryfos It grabs a column I have in this table named timestamp.  The column has a binary data type. This seems to be the problem.  I chose a table on our already implemented database, and it happens to be one with a binary type column.

Comment: @apokryfos I added an image in my question to show the stream in my array.  Thanks again for the help.  Hope that will help someone else coming across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Type is not supported` is actually coming from PHP's JSON serializer. There are only a very few types that PHP cannot serialise and the one that seems to be causing the issue in your particular case is a stream resource.

In order to check what is actually serialized in your model you will need to call:

```
$user = UserSecurity::where('userName', $userName)->get();
$user->map->jsonSerialize()->dd();
```

`jsonSerialize` exists because all Laravel models implement the [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface.

This will dump a collection of arrays of what PHP will attempt to serialise as JSON. The contents of this array are recursively serialised.

The default implementation of `JsonSerializable` in `Model` will attempt to serialize all model `attributes` but first will attempt to cast and call all accessors on attributes. This may or may not cause issues. At any rate the solution here is to figure out why there's a resource being returned in the `jsonSerialize` method and figure out the best way to hide it. Normally you can hide attributes by using

```
protected $hidden = [ 'timestamp' ];
```

however from your question it seems that the answer may not be so straight forward so may need to dig deeper.

Comment: Adding $hidden fixed most of the solutions everyone else had and my original also works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the following in the top of your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

and the controller must be like:

```
public function find($userName){
    $user = UserSecurity::where('userName', $userName)->get();
    return Response::json($user, 200);
}
```

Comment: I made this change.  I now get this error `Error encoding model [App\UserSecurity] with ID [16652] to JSON: Type is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

PLease try like this

```
return response()->json(['status' => true, 'data' => $user],200);
```

I am already using this in my code
[image]

Comment: Same error. **Type is not supported** However the stacktrace has this.  `ResponseFactory->json(array('status' => true, 'data' => object(Collection)`  Which tells me it is a collection, though I have tried another fix where we change that to an array.  This also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `where('...')->get()` returns a collection which cannot be used in `response()->json()`.
Try using:

```
public function find($userName){
    $user = UserSecurity::where('userName', $userName)->first();
    return response()->json(['data' => $user->toArray()], 200);
}
```

Comment: I made this change, I have the same error.  I did notice this looked weird.

`ResponseFactory->json(array('data' => array(array('usersecurityid' => 111...`

Which looks like a weird input `array(array(array(`  Is there any information on these and what their input needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

here is just a typo error, you must write `response()` in lowercase instead or `Response()` because Response is a class, while response() is a magic Laravel function which already instantiates the class Response, and that you can use to return a Response instance.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried that.  It made no change, but I will indeed keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the following in the top of your controller
then this code will help you.

```html
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

Comment: Adding that made no direct change.  I did change `Response->json` to `Response::json` to try and use that Response class.  I have this error now though. `Error encoding model [App\UserSecurity] with ID [16652] to JSON: Type is not supported`